# How do I get user input in the middle of a PHP method?

Tags: php, methods, form-submit

I'm writing a PHP game using classes, and I'm trying to figure out how to get user input in the middle of the main gameplay method.  I understand the concept of submitting data from an HTML form and having the PHP script retrieve that data using `$_GET` or `$_POST`, but I don't know how to have this happen in the middle of the method (if that is the best way to handle this).  Here's the gameplay class:

```
class GamePlay
{
    $playerChoice="";
    $gameOver="false";

    public function play() {
        while !($this->gameOver) {
            doSomething();
            $this->playerChoice=$this->getPlayerInput();
            doSomethingElse();
        }
    }

    public function getPlayerInput() {
        echo '<form name="playerForm" "method="post">';
            echo '<input type="submit" name="submit" value="do this" />';
            echo '<input type="submit" name="submit" value="do that" />';
        echo '</form>';

        $input=$_POST['submit'];
        return $input;
    }
}
```

But the script ends up executing `doSomethingElse()` without waiting for the user to submit data, and I want the user to submit before the script moves on.  What should I do instead?

Comment: "I understand the concept of submitting data from an HTML form" --- no you don't. Otherwise you know that you can retrieve data from $_GET or $_POST in any place of your script.

Comment: The user isn't submitting data because your script is assuming the user has already sent it before they even get the form to submit.

Answer (score 3):

You have a misconception about the basics of how HTTP requests work.

Your script should deal with each submission of the form independently.  In that I mean the script should process the request, display the form, and terminate execution.  Then when the user hits submit your script will be executed again.  You will need to use something like [sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php) or [cookies](http://php.net/manual/en/features.cookies.php) to preserve state between user requests.

Answer (score 0):

Usually input is taken from the user or ajax that sends a request to the server (either a link or ajax object).  You should have the first half of your function on one page and a completion on the second page (reached by a link or something).

```
public function play(){
  while !($this->gameOver){
   doSomething();
  }
}

public function getPlayerInput(){
  echo '<form name="playerForm" "method="post" action="action.php">';
  echo '<input type="submit" name="submit" value="do this" />';
  echo '<input type="submit" name="submit" value="do that" />';
  echo '</form>';
  $input=$_POST['submit'];
  return $input;
}
```

Then a second page action.php can process by reading $_POST variable and doSomethingElse with it.

Comment: ok, but will that second page have access to the properties of the GamePlay object that ran getPlayerInput(), or do I need to make a session to make that information available?

Comment: @sigil You have to use sessions, as http is a stateless protocol. Even the original page, if accessed a second time does not have access to the properties without sessions

Answer (score 0):

You have to get a better grasp on how the input works in php.

You can't have the user to input data into the middle of a script. When the php script start to execute all the user input is already done and you have just to process it.

Try to split your method into two to simulate the intended behaviour

```
class GamePlay
{
  $playerChoice="";
  $gameOver="false";

  public function pendingInput() {
    // check for input into $_GET or $_POST and return data or false
    // something like (this function maybe a lot more complicate (or splitted
    // into smaller ones): 
      if (isset($_POST['submit']) {
         // always check user input for forgeries
         // you have to write the sanitize function obviously
         $input=sanitize($_POST['submit']); 
        return $input;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
  }

  public function play(){
      if (!$this->gameOver) {
         $input =  $this->pendingInput();
         if($input) {
            $this->applyUserMove($input);
            $this->doComputerMove();
         }
         $this->getPlayerInput();
      } else {
         $this->gameEnds();
      }
  }

  public function getPlayerInput(){
      echo '<form name="playerForm" "method="post">';
      echo '<input type="submit" name="submit" value="do this" />';
      echo '<input type="submit" name="submit" value="do that" />';
      echo '</form>';
  }

  public function gameEnds() {
      echo 'The game is over. The winner is blah blah ... ';
      echo 'play another game?';
      echo 'link to start game...';
  }

}
```

You have to think on a single run of the while loop you designed in your question. Use sessions (as http is stateless) and let the server/client take care of the loop.

**Notice:** This is just an approach to the problem, there are others but this is similar to your intended solutions.

**Some additional hints:** You can think of a php game as a [Finite State Automata](http://www.eti.pg.gda.pl/katedry/kiw/pracownicy/Jan.Daciuk/personal/thesis/node12.html):

- you get input from outside
- change your internal status
- output for inform user of your new status
- eventually wait for input

You can use a dispatcher to select the status and write a method for every state or just do a kitchen sink method like applyUserMove and operate the switch internally. Either way the work (as program) you have to do is the same.